# How to use mocha outside of unit tests?

Tags: ruby, ruby-mocha

I'm trying to use mocha outside of unit tests to mock an Net::HTTPResponse object. here is a simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby -w

require 'net/http'

require 'rubygems'
require 'mocha'

response = mock('Net::HTTPResponse')
response.stubs(:code => '500', :message => "Failed", :content_type => "text/plaint", :body => '')
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `mock' for main:Object (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using the fakeweb gem for this. It's designed to stub out http requests.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'fakeweb'

FakeWeb.register_uri(:get, "http://something.com/", :body => "", :status => ["500", "Server Error"])
```

More info: https://github.com/chrisk/fakeweb